# Android: Issue with several ExpandableListView in my layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a main Scrollview layout with a LinearLayout including several elements:

- ExpandableListView #1 (1 children for yet)
- TextView
- ExpandableListView #2 (1 children for yet)
- Several text views

The issue I encounter is when I click on any of the ExpandableListView, le display by itself is not expanding.

You can see the non-expanded view in this screen-capture (not clikced yet):

https://plus.google.com/photos/101037819512700772601/albums/5870915782494751761/5870915784486932322

You can see the should be expanded view (once I clicked on the ExpandableListViews) in this screen captures:

https://plus.google.com/photos/101037819512700772601/albums/5870915782494751761/5870915780856077570

There you have my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ExpandableListView 
                android:id="@+id/expandableView" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            </ExpandableListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/providerNameView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="ABCDEF1"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />         

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/expandableView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </ExpandableListView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/providerNameView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="ABCDEF2"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />         

             . . . 

    </LinearLayout>     

</ScrollView>
```

Do you have a solution for my issue?

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You can't nest multiple vertical scrolling views. Otherwise you're going to have a field day trying to override the appropriate touch events to get everything right.

If you need other views to scroll as the list scrolls, you can simply add header/footer views. If you need that to be 'sticky' a cursory Google search came up with [Sticky headers](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library.

Comment: I don't need to have nested scrolling elements, I need this only for the expandable behavior.

Comment: Your layout is nesting two ExpandableLists in a ScrollView. That won't work correctly unless you override and implement a bunch of custom touch intercept logic. Replace the ScrollView with something non-scrolling.

Comment: The result won't fit in one screen, it's why I've put the ScrollView.

Comment: Which is why I suggested you use a listview with headers/footers as needed. You CAN'T NEST VERTICAL SCROLLING WIDGETS. I don't know how else to communicate that.

Comment: Ok. I'll search about header/footer usage.